# Prove $\lim_{x \to 5} \left( x^2+x+1 \right )=31$

Tags: limits

Prove using the precise definition of limit that:
$$
\lim_{x \to 5} \left( x^2+x+1 \right )=31
$$

I'm not too sure if I got it right just want to double check i got 
$$
-5\delta = \epsilon \\
\delta = -\frac \epsilon 5 \\     
\delta = \min \left ( -\frac \epsilon 5, 1 \right )
$$

Answer (score 3):

Be careful. It looks like you'll be choosing a negative $\delta$ above, and you need $\delta > 0$. As a hint, note that $$|x^2 + x + 1 - 31| = |(x-5)(x+6)| = |x-5|\,|x+6|.$$
Therefore, if you have that $|x-5| < \delta$, you find that $$|x^2+x+1-31| < \delta \,|x+6|.$$

Your job now is to be judicious in deciding what $\delta$ to use. In particular, if you let $\delta = \min(\epsilon/12, 1)$ then you should have that $\delta\, |x+6| < (\epsilon/12)(12) = \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=5\pm\delta$ then

$$x^2+x+1=25+\pm 10\delta +\delta^2+5\pm \delta+1=31\pm11\delta+\delta^2$$ and $$(x^2+x+1)-31=\delta^2\pm 11\delta=\delta (\delta\pm 11)$$

Then if $|\delta|\lt 1$ we have $|\delta(\delta\pm 11)|\lt 12\delta\lt \epsilon$  provided also $\delta \lt \cfrac {\epsilon}{12}$